# Check if a directory is a (file system) root

Tags: python

I have a script that searches for a directory containing a specific file, starting from the current directory and going up the tree (think of trying to find out where the `.git` directory sits).

My method looks like this:

```
def getDir(self,cwd):
  path = os.path.abspath(cwd)
  if not os.path.isdir(path):
    raise RuntimeError("getDir should not be run on files")
  if FILE in os.listdir(path):
    return path
  parent = os.path.join(path, os.path.pardir)
  if os.access(parent, os.R_OK) and os.access(parent, os.X_OK):
    return self.getDir(parent)
  else
    return None
```

Now the problem with this method is that, if it cannot find the directory, it loops (and eventually stack-overflows) because apparently joining `/` and `..` gives you `/` again. I tried comparing `path` with `parent` or their `repr`s, but that did not work (they were always distinct). My workaround for now is to include a depth counter in the recursive method and stop at some random maximum threshold.

My question is thus, is there a reliable cross-platform way to check whether I have reached a root in the file system?

Comment: I'm not completely sure if it is reliable on all platforms, but if os.path.dirname(path)==path, then it seems like path is the root.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think you can find out if it's a file system root portably, however I'd suggest doing a call to [`os.path.realpath()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.realpath) on both the current dir and your calculated parent and compare if they're the same -- this means you are spinning your wheels and there's no point in proceeding.

For example:

```
>>> os.path.realpath('/usr/bin/..')
'/usr'
>>> os.path.realpath('/usr/bin/../..')
'/'
>>> os.path.realpath('/usr/bin/../../..')
'/'
>>> os.path.realpath('/..')
'/'
```

Answer (score 25):

```
if os.path.dirname(path) == path:
    # you have yourself root.
    # works on Windows and *nix paths.
    # does NOT work on Windows shares (\\server\share)
```

Comment: It does work on windows shares, but it doesn't denote the share to be the root... it thinks of \\server as the root.  That honestly makes more sense IMO anyway.

Comment: @nacitarsevaht You are probably right. Thinking of \\server as root does make more sense, but makes less practical use, as enumerating contents of \\server through normal tools that do "list dir" is hardly practical.

Comment: This answer doesn't work if the path contains ".." elements, such as in @FatalError's answer.

Answer (score 3):

With `pathlib.Path` there's a sharp edge if one wants to do it properly. For `Path("~/../../")` to work, one has to use `expanduser()` and `resolve()` in correct order:

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path("~/../..")
path = path.expanduser().resolve()
if path.parent == path:
    print("This points to fs root!")
```

Otherwise, the condition will end up with a path that is `../` away from CWD.

Answer (score 1):

This works for us on Linux. Not sure about Windows, however:

```
def _find_root(start, stop, func=os.path.exists):
    """Search up the start hierarchy for stop; return None at the FS root.

    Uses func() to determine if stop exists; default is os.path.exists().
    """
    if func(os.path.join(start, stop)):
        return start
    else:
        if os.path.samefile(start, os.path.dirname(start)):
           return None
        else:
           return _find_root(os.path.dirname(start), stop)
```

We use os.path.normpath(start) in the call to this function.

Answer (score 0):

[`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) paths have an `anchor` property to do just that. So you can just check if you're at the absolute path's root:

```
from pathlib import Path

absolute_path = Path(path_to_check).absolute()
if absolute_path == Path(absolute_path.anchor):
   print("it's a root")
```

It's your choice whether to use `absolute` or `resolve`, they handle symlinks differently.

Comment: Note: in order for this to work with paths containing `../`, the code _has to_ use `resolve()`.